# json request cross domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I've been trying to get the following request to work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domainB.com/jsonfile.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Of course I'm **calling this from domainA.com**.

Am I correct in assuming that this will NEVER EVER work unless I find a way to add the

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

to the response header?

Comment: there are 2 options either use CORS(Access-Control-Allow-Origin) or use jsonp... both require the external server to add the corresponding support

Comment: Or option 3, do the ajax call to your own server, and use the serverside for cross domain calls.

Comment: also CORS and jsonp are 2 different ways to handle Cross Domain Requests... they should not be used together

Comment: But either way I need for the ISP to perform some sort of setup right? I'm using an ISP called UnoEuro and I'm not sure they support that.

Comment: it is not the ISP who need to change it.. it is the owner of the site

Comment: Ah! So if I create a piece of php code to return my json I can just from within that code add the header?